# Returning data of arbitrary simple types from a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm updating some existing C++ code that dates back about 25 years.  The code's got a number of "apply function to collection"-type functions with signatures such as

```
void *CNode::DoUntil(CNode *aRoot, TestFunc1 aFunc, void *aParam)
```

where `aFunc` has the signature

```
void *(*TestFunc1)(CNode *xNode, void *xParam)
```

This applies `aFunc` to each item in a collection until `aFunc` returns non-NULL.  Most of the time, this is used to produce operations such as "find" which return a pointer to the found object, but sometimes, it's operations such as "count", where an integer gets stuffed into the `void *` return value and pulled back out again by the caller.  Needless to say, this is 1) ugly, and 2) causes compilers to scream.  For example:

```
dataItemID = (itemID)CNode::DoUntil(getDatabase(), FindItemFuncPtr, &data)
```

produces the error `cast from pointer to smaller type 'itemID' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information`.

What's a suitably idiomatic way to return data of arbitrary type from a function in this situation?  At a bare minimum, it needs to support integers, booleans, and pointers, and because of the compiler I'm using, it can't use any constructs newer than C++ 11.

I don't want to do a major re-write of the code; ideally, I'd just change the functions involved to return a `std::any`, but that's part of C++ 17, not C++ 11.

Comment: The compilers should not have started screaming - they should have always screamed. I would use some casts - using something like std::any would be a quite major re-write.

Comment: Can you clarify with a code sample that would cause compiler screaming, and the associated scream?

Comment: You can use `boost` version of `any`/`variant` in C++11.

Comment: @Mark To make the compiler stop complaining, cast the `void*` to an integer type of equal size before you then truncate it, eg: `dataItemID = (itemID) (uintptr_t) CNode::DoUntil(getDatabase(), FindItemFuncPtr, &data);` You really should not be using C style casts in C++, though. Use C++ style casts instead, eg: `dataItemID = static_cast<itemID>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(CNode::DoUntil(getDatabase(), FindItemFuncPtr, &data)));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I'm pretty sure this code pre-dates C++-style casts.  It's got copyright dates from the early 1990s, and the newest dated comments I've seen are from the late 1990s.

Comment: @Mark just because it was written way back then doesn't mean you can't update it now to more modern practices. Personally, I would probably just use a template instead, eg: `template<typename RetType, typename ParamType> RetType CNode::DoUntil(CNode *aRoot, RetType (*aFunc)(CNode *xNode, ParamType xParam), ParamType aParam) { for (each node in xNode) { RetType ret = aFunc(node, aParam); if (ret) return ret; } return RetType(); }` ... `dataItemID = CNode::DoUntil<itemID, DataType*>(getDatabase(), FindItemFuncPtr, &data);`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is too many changes, but I would go for something like:

```
enum class EIterationStep
{
    Break,
    Continue
};

enum class EIterationStatus 
{
    Interrupted,
    Finished
};

EIterationStatus CNode::DoUntil(CNode *aRoot, std::function<EIterationStep(CNode *)> func);
```

I assume that the input `void*` is the user data which can now be captured in lambda/functor.
You might change enum by `bool` with correct convention (and possibly by `void` for `DoUntil` if result not used).

You might pass capturing lambda to update `count` or found item.

I would change pointer by reference if possible.

You can change `std::function` by template if you want to.